# Raspberry Pi bluez C++, why does the bind() function return -1 (fail)?

Tags: bluetooth, bind

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W that I'm trying to write code to connect to. The `bind()` command is failing with -1. I can't use `BDADDR_ANY` as I get a compile error of:

> taking address of temporary

I'm using `my_bdaddr_any` instead but that is what gets the -1 return. If I use `my_bdaddr_all` or `my_bdaddr_local`, the bind works, but the `accept()` never works. Here is my code snippet:

```
char buf[1024] = {0};   
int bluetoothSocket, client, bytes_read;         
struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = {0};
struct sockaddr_rc client_addr = {0};

socklen_t opt = sizeof(client_addr);    

bdaddr_t my_bdaddr_any = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
bdaddr_t my_bdaddr_all = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
bdaddr_t my_bdaddr_local = {0, 0, 0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};     

bluetoothSocket = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);     

loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = (bdaddr_t &) my_bdaddr_all;                
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;

int ret = -1;

if(ret = bind(bluetoothSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr)) == -1)    
{
    printf("Bluetooth bind failed.\n");
    return 0;
}

listen(bluetoothSocket, 1);

client = accept(bluetoothSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &opt);

if (client == -1)
{
    close(client);" 
}

ba2str(&loc_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf);
fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
if (bytes_read > 0) 
{
    printf("Bluetooth bytes received [%s]\n", buf);
}   
close(client);
close(bluetoothSocket);
return;
```

Comment: Did you check `errno`?

Comment: I just did and got message "Address already in use". That doesn't make sense, but I better investigate. I was previously trying to find out how to get errno, but discovered that it is a global variable that was set by the function and all I needed to do was add this code: `printf("Bluetooth bind failed. ERRNO=%d\n", errno); char *errorMessage = strerror_r(errno, buf, 1024); printf("%s\n", errorMessage);`

Answer (score 0):

The bind() problem was due to another program that was running which was already bound to the bluetooth device. I added this code in order to find out why I kept getting the -1 on bind().

```
if (ret = bind(bluetoothSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr)) == -1)   
{
    printf("Bluetooth bind failed. ERRNO=%d\n", errno);
    char *errorMessage = strerror_r(errno, buf, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", errorMessage);
    return 0;
}
```